# Can't set up an avd to use for an emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

So just now I decided to switch over to Android Studio from Eclipse, everything seems to be fine except that I can't even find the menu to add a new virtual device.

On the Android dev website it says it should be in Tools>Android>AVD Manager or to execute "android avd" from the tools directory, but **I don't have a tools directory.**

I installed it with pretty much all the default settings so i don't know how it's not there.

Comment: alt+t to expanding the tools in toolbar

Comment: No, that didn't do anything, it just. I have a tools button up with all the others like file and edit, but I can't seem to find a tools directory within the android studio directory so I can't run it that way either

Answer (score 0):

Fixed itself sort of. I tried running a project and android studio had a message come up there that allowed me to install the part that was missing, I don't know why I didn't have it at the beginning though.